# What is the difference between widget and app?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm newer in web programming so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you.

what is difference between widget and app in web programming?

Comment: widgets cannot be developed without app , app content classes and user interface, and its depending in what language you are working on , Java for android , Objective C for IOS iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term widget implies that it is designed to be reused, so it can be a module or an independent piece of code which can be reused in several parts of an app.

The app is the global application which provides full functionality

Answer (score 1):

A widget is usually a small application with limited functionality. It usually, not always, will have one specific purpose. 
An app is much broader and is short for application which can encompass any number of things.

Answer (score 1):

An application is the full website with pages, module and co, and a widget is a simple reusable code that has a simple functionnality. The widget can be used in an application when inserted in one or multiple pages. 
A widget can be for example : a small programm to retrieve the weather, the members that have anniversary today,...

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser is an application. The extensions you add to it are widgets.

A Content Management System is an application. The datepicker plugin that it uses to choose dates is a widget.

Stackoverflow is an application. The ask a question text editor is a widget.

"Application" usually describes a project as a whole, while "widget" describes a small, usually reusable part of it.

Answer (score 1):

A widget is part of an application. You cannot run a web widget standalone. It must be embedded in within an application.

These terms are fluid and subject to marketing efforts. For example, the term widget used to exclusively mean a UI element and now the term is being used by Android for applications that run in the background when not is use. According to the NY Times "Widgets are basically self-contained mini programs that live and run on the phone’s home screen."

So it's important to differentiate between the term "widget" being used in a UI context,  the term used in a web context and term in an Android context.